# LibreOffice 5.4.4.2 Symbol Fonts show up as BOXES

Tags: libreoffice, ppa, fonts

Using 16.04.4 LTS and LibreOffice [PPA] Version: 5.4.4.2; Build ID: 1:5.4.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1; CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 4.13; UI render: GL; VCL: gtk2; Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8).

Symbol FONT and many other glyph-type symbols stopped working on upgrade to to the PPA.  They just appear as boxes.  Is this a bug, or a "feature" that I don't know how to reverse?

Thanks

Comment: Which exact font does not work? OpenSymbol shown normally on my 5.4.4.2 on Xenial.

Comment: OpenSymbol does not work either.

Comment: Try to view problematic fonts in `gucharmap` or `font-manager`. And you can always reset your libreoffice profile in home folder by `rm -rf $HOME/.config/libreoffice`.

Comment: They look okay with FONT VIEWER.  Reseting the LO config does not solve.  This error occurred with the last LO PPA update.